# Report: Last Activity date 30, 60 day

Tags: reporting, date, activity

I'm trying to run a report and group them by 30, 60, 90 days last activity date. Do I filter by 30, 60, 90 day or how should i do this?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to create a formula field on the object in question:

```
FLOOR((TODAY()-LastActivityDate)/30)*30
```

This will give you 30, 60, 90, 120, etc days since the last activity. From there, you can group this in a report.

Note that if you simply were interested in the last three or four months, you could choose to summarize your report by adding a grouping for Last Activity, then using the dropdown menu to "Group Dates By > Calendar Month."

For the filter itself, you can say something like:

> Last Activity equals LAST 90 DAYS